# Python flask webpage single item page for multiple item

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am doing a flask website project and im trying to get create an individual item page for each of my items. Im using sqlite for the database.

Below is the html code for my homepage:

```
{% extends "base-template.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Valves</h1>
<form action="/product-info" methods=["link", "post"] class="valve-box">


    {% for valve in valve_list %}
        <li>

            <b>Name/Model:</b> {{ valve['item_name'] }}<br> <b>Price:</b> {{     valve['item_price'] }}$
            <input type="submit" value="Go to info page"/>


        </li> 
    {% endfor %}



</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This on html is basically a verticle list of items. When i'm interested in an item, I press the button next to the item, and the routes file in my folder will takes me to the product-info page.

Below is html code for my product info page:

```
{% extends "base-template.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Information</h1>

<form class="valve-box">

    {% for valve in valve_list %}
        <li>

            <b>Item ID:</b> {{ valve['item_id'] }}<br> <b>Name/Model:</b> {{     valve['item_name'] }}<br> <b>Description:</b> {{ valve['description'] }}<br>     <b>Price:</b> {{ valve['item_price'] }}$



        </li> 
    {% endfor %}


</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is i need a interactive product info page that only shows information of the product that the user was interested and pressed on. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `@app.route` in your Python file to display an individual product's information, and then add a link for each valve.  It could look like this:

```
<!-- other HTML up here -->
{% for valve in valve_list %}
    <li>
        <b>Item ID:</b> {{ valve['item_id'] }}<br> 
        <b>Name/Model:</b> {{ valve['item_name'] }}<br> 
        <b>Description:</b> {{ valve['description'] }}<br>     
        <b>Price:</b> {{ valve['item_price'] }}$
        <a href='{{ url_for("show_valve", valve_id=valve["item_id"]) }}'>Show detail</a>
    </li> 
{% endfor %}
<!-- the rest of your HTML -->
```

Your new function in the Python file will accept the ID sent by your template, and you can then build a page just for that item.  Here's an example of what I'm thinking for your new function in the Python code:

```
@app.route('whatever/address/you/want')
def show_valve(valve_id):
    # get your list of valves from wherever it comes from
    for valve in valves:
        if valve["item_id"] == valve_id:
            target_valve = valve
            break
    return render_template('showValveDetail.html', valve=target_valve)
```

Comment: One more question, to display the individual product's information, i have to some how link whatever item user clicked on in the html file to my routes file. My initial idea for this was to create a variable like "the_item_user_just_clicked_on" in the html file and import the variable to the python routes fle, but on docs it says you cannot have variables in html. If u could give some suggestions for how to do that that would be great, thanks

Comment: If you set up your new route function, here I've named it `show_valve` but you could name it something else, to accept some input named `valve`, the HTML code I have in the answer is already sending `valve["item_id"]`.  So, in your Python code, you can use that ID to search through your valve list and find the one you need (assuming that `"item_id"` is unique to each `valve`).

Comment: Just tried this and for some reason the show_valve function call is not working right as it says show_valve takes exactly 1 value, 0 given.

Comment: Ok the problem was the route actually needs to be like this @website.route('/<valve_id>') for reasons unknown because im so bad at this flask/htm/python. Got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079710/url-for-in-flask-html-python-project-not-working